# Android WebView is not showing content for some URLs

Tags: android, webview, ionic-framework, html-framework-7

I created webView and i want to load some website inside it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "http://example.com";
    WebView webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.loadUrl(url);


}}
```

When i set url to be any website - it is working. But for some websites that use frameworks such as Framework7 or ionic - webview is empty.

What should I do?

Comment: Try this one: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en and tell us what errors console/network tabs show.

Comment: thank you for interesting link but there are no errors when i open this URL in Chrome

Comment: Wow, that's weird

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
WebView  webViewurl = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webViewurl.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewurl.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        final Activity activity = this;
        webViewurl.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        webViewurl.loadUrl("http://example.com/");
```

Comment: check your url in browser@moonvader